# Convert X509certificate to PKCS12

Tags: java, security

I am new to java security field. I went through all possible thread to find my answer but to no use.
I have X509Certificate and i need to convert this certificate into PKCS12 format. How do i achieve this using java api. any code snippet would be helpful.

Comment: Do you know if this is only the public/private key export or the keystore? You can check by using the `keytool` commd from the java sdk: `keytool -list -keystore [certificate filename]` (you might need to enter a password). If this is a keystore it will list its content and you can follow my answer below

Comment: This is not a keystore. i ran the command what you mentioned, i received an error invalid keystore format

Comment: afik PKCS12 is a keystore format(like JKS), a container for private and public keys(in X.509 format). do you mean you want to put public key entry in the keystore ?

Comment: I created an csr using JCRYPTO_X509CertRequest and gave it to CA for signing it. I got back a X509 certificate.  So i need to put public, private key along with certificate in pkcs12 format.

Answer (score 1):

Since I find Java KeyTool haunting to use, we use KeyStore Explorer (https://keystore-explorer.org/) to view/create/alter Java KeyStores. To achieve what you want, you can create a new PKCS12 keystore and import the X509 certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you already have your private key entry in a PKCS12 keystore, you can use `keytool`  with `-importcert` command. 
It should look something like

```
keytool -importcert -file <certificate.cer> -keystore <keystore.p12> -storetype pkcs12 -alias <alias>
```

details for usage of keytool at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/keytool.html

If you have your private key in a JKS keystore instead, you might first need to import that entry into a PKCS12 store using `-importkeystore`

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore abc.jks -destkeystore abc.p12 -deststoretype pkcs12
```

*when you give a non existent file as `destkeystore`, a new one will be created.*